# Create single zip from files from separate google drive folders

Tags: google-drive-api

Is it possible to create a single zip from separate files located in different google drive folders?

Answer (score 1):

There is the ability to create archives from different files in the old Docs List API:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_archives_of_documents_and_files

However, Drive API does not have a similar call. You can either use the deprecated API which will work until April 20, 2015 or you can just grab the files you want via Drive API and perform the zip creation within your app directly.